# Prove that a linear map rotating a vector through an angle is an automorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was asked to prove that the rotation $t_\theta \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is an automorphism, where $\theta$ is the angle a vector is rotated. I decided to use polar coordinates to simplify the proof. Therefore, the map is given by $$\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi + \theta \end{pmatrix}$$

First, we prove that $t_\theta$ is injective. Assume $t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1\end{pmatrix}) = t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix})$. Then $\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1 + \theta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 + \theta \end{pmatrix}$. Since column vectors are equal only when their components are equal, $r_1 = r_2$ and $\phi_1 + \theta = \phi_2 + \theta$. Thus, $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ and $\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix}$. Since $t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1 \end{pmatrix}) = t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix})$ implies that $\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix}$, $t_\theta$ is injective.

This proof looks convincing so far. Consider, however, two vectors $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi + 2\pi \end{pmatrix}$. The images of these vectors under $t_\theta$ are $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi + \theta\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi + 2\pi + \theta\end{pmatrix}$, respectively. These two vectors are "equal" because a rotation has a period of $2\pi$. By "equal," we mean that the vectors are related by an equivalence relation. Does the "equal" nature of these two vectors make the rotation non-injective?

Second, we prove that $t_\theta$ is surjective. Let $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi\end{pmatrix}$ be an arbitrary element of the codomain. Then $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi \end{pmatrix}$ is the image of $\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi - \theta\end{pmatrix}$ under $t_\theta$. Since every vector in the codomain corresponds to a vector in the domain, $t_\theta$ is surjective.

Third, we prove that $t_\theta$ preserves addition. $$\begin{eqnarray}t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix}) &=& t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_1 + r_2 \\ \phi_1 + \phi_2 \end{pmatrix}) \\&=& \begin{pmatrix} r_1 + r_2 \\ \phi_1 + \phi_2 + \theta \end{pmatrix} \\ &=& \begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1 + \theta\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix} \\&=& t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ \phi_1 \end{pmatrix}) + t_\theta(\begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 - \theta\end{pmatrix})\end{eqnarray}$$

Since $\begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2\end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ \phi_2 - \theta \end{pmatrix}$, $t_\theta$ does not preserve addition. Thus, the rotation is not an automorphism.

Since $r$ and $\phi$ are both real numbers with no restrictions, this cannot be an issue with the space used for the domain and codomain; that is, $\mathbb R^2$ is a valid space to use polar coordinates in.

Where did I go wrong? Either it is an error in my proof or an error in my assumptions about the space or rotation.

Comment: A rotation is a linear transformation hence there exists a matrix $A$ such that $f(x)=Ax$ where $x$ is the vector in question. So $A(x+y)=Ax+Ay$ and it preserves addition.

Comment: The error is assuming the angle of the sum is the sum of the angles.

Comment: The problem you're having comes from the fact you're saying the vectors $(x,\theta)$ and $(x,\theta+2\pi)$ are the same but remember that given $a,b$ in $X \times X$, they're equal if and only if their coordinates match. In case of polar coordinates you'd hvae to work modulo $2\pi$ with the angle.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $t_\theta$ preserves addition is quite wrong. The problem is that the sum of two points $(r_1, \phi_1)$ and $(r_2, \phi_2)$ is not $(r_1+r_2, \phi_1+\phi_2)$ but something much more complicated in general. For this reason, polar coordinates are not a good choice for this problem.

If you still wish to use them, we can identify $\Bbb{R}^2$ with $\Bbb{C}$ so that the point with polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$ becomes the complex number $re^{i\phi}$.

Then your map $t_\theta : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ acts as $t_\theta(re^{i\phi}) = re^{i(\phi+\theta)} = re^{i\phi}e^{i\theta}$ so it's is simply multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.

Now it is easy to show that it preserves addition:
$$t_{\theta}(r_1e^{i\phi_1} + r_2e^{i\phi_2}) = (r_1e^{i\phi_1} + r_2e^{i\phi_1})e^{i\theta} = r_1e^{i\phi_1}e^{i\theta} + r_2e^{i\phi_1}e^{i\theta} = t_\theta(r_1e^{i\phi_1})+t_\theta(r_2e^{i\phi_2}).$$